# xml closing tags are improperly closing

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with the google map api v3, and am creating xml data as such:

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
 $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
 $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
 $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Which is giving me the results of the following in the source code:

```
<markers>
  <marker name="Test Item 1" address="939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.386337" lng="-122.085823" distance="27.109728219880356"/>           
  <marker name="Test Item 2" address="790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.387138" lng="-122.083237" distance="27.139837055162673"/>               
</markers>
```

Should be no issues there, but when I inspect element they are slightly different.

```
<markers>
  <marker name="Test Item 1" address="939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.386337" lng="-122.085823" distance="27.109728219880356">           
     <marker name="Test Item 2" address="790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA" lat="37.387138" lng="-122.083237" distance="27.139837055162673"></marker>
  </marker>               
</markers>
```

Which is of course incorrect. Currently after running a search, it doesn't pick up results (though this marker data is created on the page), and the search dumps into the pacific ocean with no markers generated on the map.

I'm not sure if these are related issues, and both need to be resolved, but if the source code is wrong, and the inspected element code is what the browser is seeing then I think that needs to be resolved first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this on ?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$parnode = $dom->createElement("markers");
$dom->appendChild($parnode);

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
 $node->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
 $node->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
 $node->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
 $node->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
 $node->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
 $parnode->appendChild($node);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: I'm not seeing markers created at all anymore with this code, though from what I see it should be working...

Comment: I've got it to work when it's all on the index, that'll work for me! Thanks!

Comment: Why should this have been tried? How should have this fixed "the issue"? What actually was "the issue" this code should have been fixed?